# which is better to perform logical operations in angularjs controller or view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My website contains posts something like blog posts, a registered user can post things and any other registered user can view them, here when showing individual post I kept an follow button for to the viewer so if the viewer clicked it and follow the author(post owner). Now the problem is every time when a viewer clicked and see individual post I need to check whether viewer is already following that author or not so that I have to choose follow or following button to display. In my `angularjs controller` I have `json array` of authors(following authors). How can i check the individual post author existing in following authors in controller or is there any chance to perform this on view? O am using angularjs 1.x

Comment: Logic like that should be performed in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway you have to set a flag for the buttons choice (true for follow button and false for following button).

To set the scope of this variable you need to implement the logic in `JS` (Since its an array collection). Now in `HTML` you can show the follow or following button by using `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. (`ng-show="isFollow"`)